# How to pass application specific phrases to google-nlp api?

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I'm using Google NLP for executing voice commands in our application.

***Scenario:***
Input text: "Generate Customer Profitability Report"

Now that 'Customer Profitability' is a single entity from application perspective, Is there a way to pass set of suggestive phrases [in this case 'Customer Profitability'] to NLP api and NLP will treat it as a single phrase and respond ?

This is possible in speech api, where i can pass suggestive phrases.
Any pointers on these lines are much appreciated!